# How to Transpose in Hive

Tags: hive

I need a better approach for the below scenario in hive since hive is not supporting pivot.

Table

[image]

And I need to convert to below result.

[image]

Comment: please share sample output what do u mean by  _col1, _col2

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `conditional_emit` UDF from brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) to do this.

```
 SELECT ID, ce.feature as yes
 FROM
 table
 LATERAL VIEW conditional_emit( 
        ARRAY( col1 = 'yes',
               col2 = 'yes',
               col3 = 'yes',
               col4 = 'yes',
               col1 != 'yes' and col2 != 'yes' and col3 != 'yes' and col4 != 'yes'),
        ARRAY( 'col1', 'col2', col3', 'col4', ' ' ) ) c as ce;
```

`conditional_emit` is a UDTF which will emit a record for the array elements which are true ( in the first array passed in) with the corresponding string from the second array passed in. Note that this makes only one pass over the data, while the `UNION` would make multiple passes.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Select ID, Yes from (
SELECT ID, 'Col1' as 'Yes' where Col1  = 'yes'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'Col2' as 'Yes' where Col2  = 'yes'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'Col3' as 'Yes' where Col3  = 'yes'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'Col4' as 'Yes' where Col4  = 'yes'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, NULL as 'Yes' where Col1  != 'yes' and Col2  != 'yes' and Col3  != 'yes' and Col4  != 'yes'
) TempTable ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: This solution is an absolute disaster if you care about efficiency.